# How to best solve "void foo( const T& t = T() )" when T==void

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, void

I have a function which has an option parameter of type T.

```
template<typename T>  
void foo( const T& t = T() )  
{ t.stuff; }
```

This was all fine but I now have a scenario where T becomes `void`. In this case I expected a no-operation empty function. The only workable solution I have requires three separate declarations and I have many of these sort of methods:

```
template<typename T> 
void foo( const T& t)
{ t.stuff; }

template<typename T>
inline void foo() 
{ foo(T()); }

template<> 
inline void foo<void>() {}
```

Ideally I hope there should be a more elegant solution to overload the 'Void' function without resorting to a 3rd declaration? Especially with new C++17 solving so many things these days! A more concise syntax that was shorter coudl be nice...

Comment: If `T` is `void`, what is `t.stuff()` supposed to do? Seems like we'd *want* a compiler error. Are you actually intending a call to `foo` to be a no-op? If so, perhaps we should revisit your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler solution (in that there are only 2 overloads) would be something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo( const T& t = T() ) {
    t.stuff;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<T>>
foo() {}

// void foo(const T&); is the only viable overload for non-void T,
// since std::enable_if_t SFINAEs

// void foo(); is the only viable overload for void T,
// since const T& forms a reference to void
```

And this can be slightly shortened with alias templates since you use this pattern a lot:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename TypeIfVoid = void>
using if_void = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<T>, TypeIfVoid>;


template<typename T>
void foo(const T& t = T()) {
    t.stuff;
}

template<typename T>
if_void<T> foo() {}
```

Comment: The second version really fits the use-case hen having many functions. I was trying to achieve this but had my syntax wrong so thanks for helping solve this :) There are other answers with a single function definition but they all remain very verbose to read+use so I will accept this answer as it is clear and terse. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Two default template parameters will do it:

```
template<class T> using FallbackT = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, int, T>;

template<class T = int&, class U = FallbackT<T>>
void foo(U const& t = U()) {
    if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T>)
        t.stuff();
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/jnqnTh).

`int&` is the default for `T` so that compilation fails (default-constructing a reference at `U()`) if someone attempts to call `foo()` without either a template argument or an actual argument (try uncommenting it in the example).

I'm using `int` within `FallbackT` alias template since `U` just needs to be something that is default-constructible - this isn't visible to the user.

If you want to be fancy (and prevent misuse) you could add a variadic guard and use closure types:

```
template<
    class T = decltype([]{})&,
    class...,
    class U = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, decltype([]{}), T>>
void foo(U const& t = U()) {
    if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T>)
        t.stuff();
}
```

Here, the variadic guard prevents specifying U explicitly, as e.g. `foo<int, long>()`; the closure types make it impossible for someone to call `foo` with those types by any other means - this is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. The first version solves the use-case however it is quite verbose for applying to many functions. This would be good if there were a syntax that could abbreviate the complexity of copy-paste involved and subsequent opportunities for errors!
The 'Fancy' version requires -std=C++2a features, nice to see but I am not truly clear on what misuse this could/would avoid?

Comment: Sure, I shortened it as much as I think is possible - you're going to need some kind of alias template for the second template parameter. I also added an explanation of the "fancy" features/techniques.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I hope there should be a more elegant solution to overload the 'Void' function without resorting to a 3rd declaration? Especially with new C++17 solving so many things these days! A more concise syntax that was shorter coudl be nice...

Well... without a 3rd declaration, yes (you can use only one).

More elegant... it's question of tastes, I suppose.

More coincise syntax... well... almost the same, I suppose.

Anyway, I propose the following version, `if constexpr` and `std::conditional_t` based.

```
template <typename T,
          typename U = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, void>,
                                          int,
                                          T>>
void foo (U const & u = U{})
 {
   if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, void> )
    { /* do nothing */ }
   else
    { /* do u.stuff; */ }
 }
```

Comment: The one problem with this is that `T` has to be provided (And `U` can be deduced to something different). Of course not a problem if it's never called like `foo(value);` or `foo<base_class>(derived_object);`